# mkfs.cramfs: command not found in cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

I am trying to run shell script using Cygwin and Java. I am getting the following error

```
    mkfs.cramfs: command not found 
lib/tgzcreator.sh: line 346: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Do I need to install some other package in Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

`mkfs` is a program for managing file systems. Cygwin can't do that; the package just doesn't exist.

You'll need to look inside the script and port it to work on Cygwin. If that's even possible; if it's trying to do work with file systems you might just not be able to use it at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply,mkfs.cramfs is included in util package. Now  i am able to run the mkfs command.

Comment: @niraj: That surprises me, but fair enough. If you have a solution, post it as an answer to this question and mark it as accepted, so other people will be able to find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

in cygwin 32 bit ,cramfs will support at dev package,but 64 bits is not use